# Proof of some theorems of Mersenne number

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers

If $p$ is prime, than all composite divisors of $Mp=2^p-1$ are strong pseudoprimes to the base 2.
How can we prove this theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strong pseudoprime is a composite number that passes a strong version of a primality test.

Definition: An odd composite number $q= d · 2^s + 1 $ where $d$ is odd is called a strong (Fermat) pseudoprime to base $a$ if:

$ a^{d}\equiv 1\pmod n$

or

$a^{d\cdot 2^{r}}\equiv -1{\pmod {n}}\quad {\mbox{ for some }}0\leq r<s.$

Now, if $N=2^p-1$ where $p$ is prime, then all the divisors of $N$ are of the form $q=2kp+1$ where $k$ is positive integer, but since $2^p \equiv 1 \pmod q$, then $2^{q-1}=2^{2kp} = 2^{d.2^s} \equiv 1 \pmod q$, where $d$ is odd, but since $d$ is a multiple of $p$ where $p>2$, then, $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod q$, which means that if  $q$ is composite,  then $q$ is  strong (fermat) pseudoprime to the base $2$.

Comment: That $2p|q-1$ is proven [here](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math153/s10/history11a.pdf).

Comment: @J.G. thank you, I forgot to put a reference

Comment: The question asks to show that $q$ is a *strong* pseudoprime.  You should probably add a brief explanation for this stronger property.

Comment: @ErickWong I put a definition to pseudoprimes, in my answer

Comment: But that’s beside the point. The question is to prove that $q$ is a strong pseudoprime, not just a pseudoprime.  This requires some additional checks that are true, but left unspoken in your answer.

Comment: @ErickWong I am sorry sir, I edited my answer, do have any other advises ?

Comment: Thanks, it looks good but the justification for $2^d \equiv 1$ is lacking, if you just add a sentence justifying that $d$  must be a multiple of $p$, it would be fine.  Computing $2^{q-1}$ doesn’t contribute your argument, but making the connection between $q-1$, $d$ and $p$ will help.

Comment: @ErickWong ok sir, thank you very much

Comment: One very minor flaw is that the argument requires that $p > 2$ to justify that $d$ is a multiple of $p$.  This is okay because $2^2-1$ has no composite divisors.  But it should be stated clearly because you don’t give any argument for why $p \mid d$.

Comment: @ErickWong you are right, I edited my answer, if there are any other advises, please let me know.